# 'SO' instead of 'Stack Overflow' or 'SE' instead of 'Stack Exchange' - Which will be more preferred

Tags: discussion

Is it okay if we mention 'SO' instead of 'Stack Overflow' or 'SE' instead of 'Stack Exchange' in question-answer communication on Stack Exchange Network? Which will be more preferred or which is a good practice?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: @Oded In question-answers communication on Stack Exchange Network.

Comment: Sure it's okay. Your choice of words is absolutely up to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about Stack Overflow specifically, you should talk about `SO`. Just like if you are talking about one of the other specific sites, you should say so - e.g. Database Administrators is typically referred to as `dba.SE`.

If you are talking about the entire network, then you should talk about `SE`. If you talk about `SO` in this context, people will think you are referring only to `SO`.

**EDIT**

Whether you use the full words or the abbreviations is entirely up to you. In certain chat rooms I use the abbreviations out of laziness, because I know everyone in the room knows what I'm talking about. On the public site, I tend to use the full name, because I don't gain much at all by saving a few keystrokes, and using the abbreviation just opens the door to have to explain to someone who asks "What do you mean by `SO`?"

Comment: I think OP is referring to using initialisms instead of the full names, not asking whether he can refer to SE as SO.

Comment: @MatthewRead I see

Comment: Note, posting SO or SE here on Meta is temporary - we have a user hunting down for those (even long years after posted) and changing to the full name. [example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/102747/revisions) - and he got hundreds. :)

Comment: I definitely prefer the longer version. In chat I think it's casual enough and, as I said, I know that just about everyone reading knows exactly what I'm talking about. Outside of chat, that user is not going to find many corrections to make in my posts. :-)